# Passing common set_facts vars to multiple playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have multiple Ansible `roles` each with their own `playbook` as seen in the structure below:

```
roles/
    |-- abc/
     -- def/
     -- hij/
     -- someother/
common.yml
abc.yml
def.yml
hij.yml
```

However, all the playbooks have the `set_facts` module that sets the same vars in each playbook. i.e: So, if the `abc.yml` playbook has the below, all the other playbooks share the exact same.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
        - set_fact:
                hostname: "user"
                randomvar: "random"
```

The problem is, if one vars from the `set_facts` needs updating, that means it needs to be done in each playbook. Is there a way to create a single playbook and pass the `set_facts` vars dynamically to others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with set_fact you set up a variable while the playbook runs. So instead of using set_fact, you can use the file `group_vars\all.yml` to set variables for all hosts in your inventory. `all` is a default group for all host.

The content of this file could be:

```
hostname: user
randomvar: random
```

from now all your playbooks can use these variables. And you have only one place to change them.

Comment: And that is by creating an additional folder called `group_vars/all.yml` at the same level as `roles` folder? Do I then have to call the `all.yml` in each playbook or they'd pick it up automatically? Thanks for the response btw

Comment: the group_vars directory is in the base_directory of ansible. see https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/inventory/ . You do not need to call this file. An alternative way would be a section in your inventory-file `[all:vars]`. Under that section you can define variables for this default group too.